# Implementing adding columns with JS-grid

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jsgrid

I am working on the js-grid and I am trying to find a way to dynamically add columns to the grid. I know there is a way to add rows, but I am looking to see if the grid has this functionality to add columns with a button. I have been reading the documentation and not sure if this is possible. My Code is listed below. Any help examples or resources would be greatly appreciated.

`var data = [
    {
        "Name": "Christopher ",
        "Married": false,
        "Testing": "Here",
        "Col": "new"
    },
    {
        "Name": "David ",
        "Married": false,
        "Testing": "Here",
        "Col": "new"
    },
    {
        "Name": "Sal",
        "Married": true,
        "Testing": "Here",
        "Col": "new"
    },
    {
        "Name": "Mike",
        "Married": false,
        "Testing": "Here",
        "Col": "new"
    }
];

```
$j("#jsGrid").jsGrid({
        height: 300,
        width: "100%",

        paging: true,
        autoload: true,
        inserting: true,
        editButton: true,
        editing: true,


        pageSize: 6,

        controller: {
            loadData: function() {
            return data;
        }
    },


    onRefreshed: function(args) {
            var items = args.grid.option("data");
            console.log( items, 'lets get dangerous')
         },

    fields: [

        { name: "Name", itemTemplate:function(value, item){
            if(!value){
                value = 'new';
                return item.Name = value;
            }else{
                return item.Name = value;
            }
        }, type: "textarea", width: 50 },




        { name: "Testing", itemTemplate:function(value, item){
            if(!value){
                value = 'new';
                return item.Testing = value;
            }else{
                return item.Testing = value;
            }
        }, type: "textarea",width: 50, height: 50},


        { name: "Col", itemTemplate:function(value, item){
            if(!value){
                value = 'new';
                return item.Col = value;
            }else{
                return item.Col = value;
            }
        }, type: "textarea",width: 50, height: 50},
        { type: "control" },

    ]

});`
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add new columns setting `fields` option of the grid to the new array of columns (fields):

```
$("#grid").jsGrid("option", "fields", newFieldsArray);
```

Having initial set of fields, push new columns to it and set `fields` option of the grid.

Comment: Thanks for you reply I was able to find the custom field documentation. I do have  question though as far as designing the custom field button to add the field. Is it possible to two have another control column and change the base fuctionality of it to only add columns? that would be two control groups on one grid?